# Delay .net file upload with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have a bit of a strange situation and I've not worked with .net before so unsure if this is possible.

I have a div that contains a form, when the form is submitted the div flips over.

My problem is that when the submit button is pressed the file upload occurs so the div doesn't flip.

What Im wondering is, can you delay the file upload for X seconds until the jQuery flip function has completed, and then upload the file?

Comment: What does this have to do with .NET? If you want to do something client-side before the form is submitted, do it with client-side scripting (aka javascript).

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I'm unsure what .net is capable of, maybe theres a delay function or something?

Comment: Well... .NET is server-side scripting, by the time you get there, the post-back has already occurred, and from what you've written, it sounds like you want to do something before post-back.

Answer (score 2):

How about calling the file upload function asynchronously-ish with setTimeout? Calling it in an async-ish manner with a brief delay should allow your div to flip.

The code might look something like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){yourFileUploadFunction()}, 1);
```

See [here for more](http://blog.scottmessinger.com/post/10368818426/creating-asynchronous-functions-in-javascript) js async detail. And [here.](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/02/JavaScript-Function-Tips-and-Tricks) Also [here](http://devedge.primedirective.net/toolbox/examples/2003/CCallWrapper/index.html). There are a number of ways to use setTimeout to create an sync call...

Answer (score 1):

Try to sleep a couple of seconds before processing the upload.

On the client side:

`$("#upload").flip().delay(2000).ajax()`

(not sure the exact syntax of what you're doing but this should get you close)

Comment: Adding a sleep on the server side won't do anything. Second option looks reasonable.